# Frozen Plop Boot Manager

Tags: windows-10, usb, bios

I've been trying to update my Windows 10 Pro from the 32-bit to the 64-bit version. I'd failed during the past attempts as in the boot priority list in the BIOS of the desktop, the required bootable USB flash drive option doesn't exist. Recently, I've found out that this is likely due to the fact that the computer and the BIOS itself are quite old (more than 12 years old)

I've found an alternative way to overcome that issue, which is making use of Plop Boot Manager. I've burnt the required ISO file to an empty CD and tried to boot via it while the USB stick was connected to the computer. However, when I select the USB option in the table of the Plop's interface, the whole system freezes. I've unplugged every irrelevant USB connections, but the result was the same.

What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas As I noted in the question, my setup is already old. Since it is not feasible to buy a whole system in my country in which all those hardware are imported and the currency has literally made a hard landing, I'm planning to change my GPU with a better one that I've had for a while and that new one requires a 64-bit OS. This has led to the motivation of such an OS update. By the way, the processor is x64-based so that I can use it on the 64-bit version.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I didn't want to draw a special attention to where I am from and make up a dramatic story. I just wanted to tell that I am hardly able to build up a robust computer in accordance with the economical situation. This is why I am dealing with such an update which is regarding the OS: I want to make use of a high performance graphics card that I've bought a while ago. This is what I am able to do now, I don't want to put it aside anymore. By the way, thank you for your hospitality.

Comment: I get what you are saying.  I wasn't asking for your country of origin or how much money you have. :) I am just saying that this site is FULL of gurus that can help you even more than you know.  It is difficult to help you solve the bigger problem without knowing what there is to work with Like machine specs and the card you want to stick in there.  Even (very, VERY) old computers can boot optical media.  It makes me think that something is wrong with your boot CD/DVD.  Again, please provide specs above.  It would be very helpful and nobody will judge you for the specs.

Answer (score 1):

After some efforts, I've come across a useful documentation inside the CD to which the relevant Plop ISO file has been burnt: A file which is named as **readme.txt**.

In this file, a user who is suffering the same problem can use specific key combinations to sort out that issue. These key commands can be found at the end of **The Boot Manager** section in the text file. In my case, in which I come across the freeze problem of the whole system whilst the software tries to sort all of the USB peripherals, the combination of **Alt + U** can be used so that in the interface of the boot manager and by pressing these keys, one can manually select the relevant USB storage device.

PS This answer is based on the Plop's **plpbt-5.0.15** version.